# Error when adding service on server

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services

I have created a restful service. On client I can run the service with out no error. But trougth the Server I get error.

This is the error message:

This collection already contains an address with scheme http.  There can be at most one address per scheme in this collection. 
Parameter name: item

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solutions for this.

http://syedemad.wordpress.com/2009/05/29/wcf-this-collection-already-contains-an-address-with-scheme-http/